# Objective-C imageWithCGImage memory leak

Tags: objective-c

I want to save all my photos from assets to some folder. Doing this in loop by:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage]; 

ALAssetOrientation orientation = [representation orientation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];

CGFloat compressionQuality = 1.0;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality)];
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I have Automatic Reference Counting enabled. This code is inside autorelease pool. It has a memory leak of CGImageRef objects. If i'll make

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

twice there is no memory leak. Why? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 8):

This is one unbelievable bug in iOS. Apparently when you create an UIImage using imageWithCGImage: method it retains the original **CGImageRef** which never gets released even if you release the UIImage itself (like set it to nil if you use ARC)! So you have to release it explicitly like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
...
CGImageRelease(image.CGImage);
image = nil; // once you are done with it
```

Cost me full day of digging around until I came across this question that actually contained the answer. Who can I send the bill at Apple for all the time I spent on debugging this unspeakable bug?

**CORRECTION:** This was not an iOS bug, this was my stupid mistake. At some point I have "hijacked" **dealloc** method of UIImage through a private category to do some debugging and forgot about it. This is a WRONG thing to do, since the dealloc on the actual object never gets called in that case. So the end result is expected: UIImage didn't have a chance to do all the housekeeping it's supposed to do when being deallocated. NEVER EVER override dealloc through a private category.